# Salesforce + jquery + greasemonkey finds don't work on iframes

Tags: jquery, iframe, salesforce, greasemonkey

Anyone ever use Greasemonkey + jQuery to automate testing in Salesforce apps?

I'm trying to select a link to an Account from one of the built in Salesforce search pages you get when you click a magnifier glass icon.

This gets me the iFrame just fine:

`$('#resultsFrame')[0]`

But when I try to do this to find the link to the account:

`$('#resultsFrame').find("a:contains('MY ACCOUNT NAME HERE')").length`

It never finds the link. What's even more fustrating is if I try thing:

`alert('Ready ' + $('#resultsFrame')[0].contentDocument.childNodes[0].innerHTML);`

I get back this:

`<head></head><body></body>`

I know Salesforce does a lot of screwy HTML/JavaScript/Ajax tricks. And I just doing something wrong or should I just give up and switch to something like Apex test cases or set up a Selenium environment?

**----------------------**

**Edit**: Ok, so I tried again and added an alert to hold my code up while the page loaded. That worked (which is odd, I would have sworn I'd tried that). I can now find my element using this:

`$('#resultsFrame').contents().find("a:contains('MY ACCOUNT NAME HERE')")[0]`

Maybe I just missed the call to contents() (needed when searching iFrames) but I've done without it in other scripts.

Anyway Now I just need to know what event actually tells me the page is loaded. Wrapping everything in a `"$(document).ready( function(){..."` call didn't help.

Is there an easy way to figure out when the page is *really* loaded?

Comment: It's a dynamically populated page, apparently, so just check the presence of the element periodically in setInterval callback.

Comment: Finally got this. For starters I missed that there were iFrames all over the page. That meant I had to listen to those iFrame's separate DOMContentLoaded events.